# Modifying list object in java

Tags: java

I have a object list-

```
List<Object> sample = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and it contain following values-

```
[This is an apple., Ram is a boy., What is your name?].
```

I want to modify it like this-

```
[{ "q": "This is an apple." }, { "q": "Ram is a boy" }, { "q": "What is your name?" }]
```

How to do it?

P.S - I am new to Java. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Create a class with a `q`field (that you should name much better), put instances of that class in a list. Make sure to use the right generic type for your list: List<MayNewClass>.

Comment: Do some search about Map in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating List of `JSONObject` as below:

```
List<JSONObject> yourList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for(Object obj: sample) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("q",(String)obj);
    yourList.add(jsonObj);
}
```

Above code will create a new list with name `yourList` with required format of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom model as :

```
class CustomObject {
   String q;
   ...getters, setters etc 
}
```

and use further it as

```
List<CustomObject> = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is if you are on jdk8 or later:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is an apple.", "Ram is a boy.", "What is your name?")); 
    System.out.println(sample);

   List<Map<String,String>> transformed = sample.stream()
            .map(p -> {Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>(); m.put("q",p); return m;})
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

     System.out.println(transformed);
 }
}
```

Edit: Instead of `List<Map<String,String>>` transformed , you can also use `Map.Entry<String,String>` as well as it's just key-value pair you want in your list.